# winky virtualenv: python cannot import flask, but ipython can

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I have not run into this problem before and it has me scratching my head:

On Mac OSX (High Sierra) in a virtualenv I see do `ls -l venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask` and see the expected output.

When I load ipython and run:

```
from flask import Flask
```

again, I get the expected behavior.

typing `which python` gives 
`/Users/my_user/projects/my_project/venv/bin/python`, ok -- all looks good!

Now, when I go to a python prompt and try:

```
from flask import Flask
```

I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`

Whaaaa?

Yet ipython (installed in the same virtualenv) I have no problem.

print(os.environ['PATH']) seems right:

`/Users/my_user/projects/my_project/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/andrew/projects/go/bin:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin`

Any pointers would be helpful.

TIA

Comment: $PATH has nothing with import. Compare sys.path in ipython and python: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`.

Comment: Alas, there is the problem.  ipython has the virtualenv path, python does not.

Comment: This means that python is not from the virtual env. Have you activated the virtual env?

Comment: Yes, the virtualenv is activated

Comment: Please post the output of commands `$ ipython -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)"` and `$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)"`, both executed in your virtual environment (note the difference between them!). Note that `ipython` should be explicitly installed in the virtual environment if you want it to pick up the virtualenv's python executable. Otherwise, it will print a warning and use the first python found in path.

Comment: @hoefling: 
ipython -c "import sys; print(sys.version); 
> print(sys.executable)"
3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
/Users/my_user/projects/my_project/venv/bin/python3.6

And ...

python -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)"
3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6

Clearly, not what I want

Comment: Please execute `which python` with your venv activated. Your venv seems to be broken, maybe missing the shim to python executable. It should use the shim `venv/bin/python`. Instead, the system python executable is being used.

Comment: @hoefling

$ which python
/Users/my_ser/projects/My_project/venv/bin/python

Comment: This makes no sense - `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)"` points to the system python, while `which python` points to the venv one. Both outputs are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @hoefling : Exactly!  There is something very wonky about this virtualenv.  Indeed several virtual environments on this box have a similar problem.